# How can I place a horizontal LinearLayout ontop of another horizontal LinerLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to place 5 LinearLayouts on top of one another starting from the bottom of the screen.To keep the xml code short I'll just talk about the bottom 2, placing one on top of the other and I should be able to work the rest out from there.

The LinearLayouts are nested in a RelativeLayout just so you know.

I am able to get the bottom LinearLayout into the position I want at the bottom of the screen by using `android:gravity="bottom"`. I thought I could have been able to use this for the next LinearLayout row and it would place itself on top of the bottom row but this didn't work. When I include this that row disappears somewhere.

Here is a picture of how it looks at the minute[image].

Notie the three buttons at the top 7,8,9 (the row I want on top of the bottom row). The rows which look like they are in the right place are only there because I used `android:layout_marginTop="xxxdp"` to manually place them there as I did for all the rows beforehand but when I went to run it the bottom two rows were pushed out of sight. As I mentioned I manged to correct the bottom row with gravity.

Here is the xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Game01">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/text_score"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fifthRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eText_scoreEntry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/edtText_3DartScore"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_backspace" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/forthRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_1"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_2"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_3"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_4"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_4"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_5"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_6"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_6"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/secondRow"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomRow">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_7"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_7"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_8"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_8"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_9"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_9"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_treble"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_treble" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_0"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_0"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_enter"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_enter"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give ids to all 5 Linear layouts and place each one above each other by this attribute `android:layout_above="@id/layout_below"`. Also all 5 must have height `wrap_content`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Game01">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/text_score"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fifthRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@id/forthRow">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eText_scoreEntry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:linksClickable="false"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:text="@string/edtText_3DartScore"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_backspace" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/forthRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@id/thirdRow">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_1"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_2"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_2"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_3"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_3"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondRow"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_4"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_4"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_5"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_5"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_6"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_6"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/secondRow"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomRow">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_7"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_7"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_8"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_8"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_9"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_9"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_treble"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_treble" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_0"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_0"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_enter"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_enter"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the xml code to include it all. I tried what you said but every LinearLayout is now at the top of the screen. As can be seen here https://imgur.com/a/I9TXA8b

Comment: That's great. Worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad_______